# SQL: Group by Case Statement to sum Row Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like below. I am trying to group by subject using a case statement for every "subject" that starts with "cf" like something like the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN subject LIKE '%cf' THEN sum(Count)
FROM table
```

The goal is to just drop all the extra characters following "cf" and then sum the total count and create a new row as 'Cf' with the sum of count value as shown in the desired output.

```
subject.  count
status    2461193
priority  1042073
ta.       126295
dueDate   62560
assignee  34142
cf2122     1
cf2123.    1
cf4312.    1
cf3234.    1 
cf5464.    1
```

**desired output:**

```
subject.  count
status    2461193
priority  1042073
ta.       126295
dueDate   62560
assignee  34142
cf.       1221
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a GROUP BY based on an expression. You also need to put the wildcard for the LIKE condition *after* the prefix you want, `'cf%'`

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN subject LIKE 'cf%' THEN 'cf' 
          else subject
       end as normalized_subject,
       sum("count")
FROM the_table
group by normalized_subject
order by sum("count") desc
```

Using a column alias in the GROUP BY is a Postgres extension to the SQL language. In other DBMS products you would need to repeat the CASE expression in the GROUP BY (which is only more to type, but won't change performance)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=594b85e289be55411f188ae60c15a28f)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! While this worked to sum and group the 'cf' subjects, the only thing that went wrong was that the other values went to '1' but it should work for me!

Comment: @Blackdynomite: ah, copy and paste error `%cf` must be `cf%`. I also overlooked that your `count` is an existing column, not the result that you expect.